# How to Change Legend Type in Excel?

Tags: windows, excel, charts, legend

I have a line chart, where the chart legend also in forms of line. Is there a way I can change the legend type from colored `line` to colored `circle` or `square`?

Figure like [this. http://www.nevron.com/gallery/FullGalleries/chartActiveX/stackline/images/StackLine1.png](http://www.nevron.com/gallery/FullGalleries/chartActiveX/stackline/images/StackLine1.png)

Comment: @Jon: Do I need code to do it? I thought maybe there is a step in Excel that I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use this method to get circles, but if you want to get squares, you can change the chart to a 3-D line chart, then right-click the chart area and select '3-D Rotation'. Change everything in the Rotation section of the menu to as close to 0 as you can get it. This will make your chart show up as a regular line chart while the legend shows little cubes. After you've done that, though, you'll probably have to change the axis settings. In my experience, 3D charts tend to show too many gridlines.